# Is there a way to get a single record back through a has_many relationship in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

In my Rails (3.2) app, an `Order` has many `LineItems`. A `LineItem` has many `LineItemPayments`. A `LineItemPayment` has one `Payment`. (`LineItems` can potentially be payed for multiple times (subscriptions), which is why I have the join table there.)

I need to be able to query for order information from a payment record. I can get an array of orders via relationships, but I know they will always be the same order. Is there a way in Rails to set up the association to reflect this? If not, would it better to set up a method for retrieving the array and then picking the order out of that, or rather just storing the `order_id` with the payment and set up a direct relationship that sidesteps all this?

Comment: i did not understand what you want, but it kind of sounds like one of these ```has_many :through``` thingies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to work with the orders collection and narrow it down accordingly per your own logic.  Although you certainly 'can' add the order_id to the payment directly, that will denormalize your data (as a cache) which is only recommended when you start hitting performance bottlenecks in your queries - otherwise it's asking for trouble in the area of data integrity:

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_item_payments
  has_many :line_items, :through => :line_item_payments
  has_many :orders, :through => :line_items

  # use this to get the order quickly
  def order
    orders.first
  end

  # use this to narrow the scope on the query interface for additional modifications
  def single_order
    orders.limit(1)
  end
end

class LineItemPayment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :line_item
  belongs_to :payment
end

class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  has_many :line_item_payments
end
```

Comment: That looks promising, but I get this error: `ActiveRecord::HasOneThroughCantAssociateThroughCollection: Cannot have a has_one :through association 'Payment#order' where the :through association 'Payment#line_items' is a collection. Specify a has_one or belongs_to association in the :through option instead.`

Comment: Hmm, it seems that ActiveRecord won't size down a collection.  I guess the next best thing would in your case would be to make a helper method to extract the single order - see updated.

Comment: Yes, I think that will work, and I appreciate the advice on waiting until I start taking a performance hit before denormalizing. One question though: shouldn't those be instance methods instead of class methods?

Comment: Thanks again. (Answer marked as accepted.) This was helpful. I did end up sticking with my original association, because this work was actually part of a refactor, and the migration to populate the new `line_item_payments` table relied on that existing association.